# Параметризованный метод Java

Tags: java

Всем добрый день!

Есть вот такая структура классов:

```
public class A {
    private String name;
}


public class B extends A{
    private String name = "B";
    public B(){
        //doing smth in class B
    }
}

public class C extends A{

    private String name = "C";
    public C(){
       // doing smth in class C
    }
}
```

Мне же нужно написать метод, который принимал бы на вход потомка класса А (т.е. объект класса либо В либо С) и процессе какое-то количество раз создавал новый экземпляр переданного класса. Как это сделать?

---

**UPD**
Реализовал вот так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    testing(B.class);
}
    private static <T extends A> void testing(Class<T> type) {

    try {
        T letter = type.newInstance();
        System.out.println(letter.getName());
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Однако в таком случае вызов геттера для поля name вернет null. В чем проблема?

Comment: `method(Class<? extends A> clazz)` ?

Comment: лучше конечно фабрику, а не объект класса 'class'. из классов инстанции создавать - не круто

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. А почему не круто? И как внутри метода создать экземпляр класса наследника А?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Пример 1. (Приведение типов)**

```
   public <T extends A> T method(T object) {
      try {
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         T newInstance = (T) object.getClass().newInstance();
         //Тут дополнительный код
         return newInstance;
      } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
   }
```

Если в метод передать только объект, то происходит "стирание типов". И виртуальная машина не знает, какой именно тип она получила на входе, и расценивает как "**Любой унаследованный от класса А**". Но Java - язык со строгой типизацией и метод не может вернуть "Объект любого класса" в связи с чем в коде появляются строки:

```
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     T newInstance = (T) object.getClass().newInstance();
```

То есть строгое приведение типа и игнорирование предупреждения компилятора.
**Использование:**

```
A a1 = metnod(new B());
B b1 = metnod(new B());
```

**Пример 2. (Возвращаем объект класса родителя)**

```
public <T extends A> A method(T object) {
      try {
         A newInstance = object.getClass().newInstance();
         //Тут дополнительный код
         return newInstance;
      } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
   }
```

**Использование:**

```
A a1 = method(new B());
A a2 = method(new С());
B b1 = (B) method(new B()); // Отработает нормально
B b2 = (B) method(new С()); // Ошибка приведения типов во время выполнения
```

**Пример 3. (Избегаем приведения типов)**

```
public <T extends A> T method(T object, Class<T> type) {
      try {
         T newInstance = type.newInstance();
         //Тут дополнительный код
         return newInstance;
      } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
   }
```

**Использование:**

```
A a1 = method(new B(), B.class);
B b1 = method(new B(), B.class);
```

Comment: А зачем в примере 3 в качестве аргемента методу передается T object?

Comment: Согласно условию задания :-) "который принимал бы на вход потомка класса А (т.е. объект класса либо В либо С)" то есть я подразумевал, что Вы используете значения полей этого объекта для создания новых экземпляров. В сущности, все эти примеры на этом и основаны.

Comment: а шаблоны в методе типа <T extends A> тоже нужны чисто тогда, когда метод возвращает созданный в нем объект, если можно передать класс, и возвращать объект метод не будет, все упрощается к варианту решения предложенному  @Etki

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1** от @Etki. Через reflection:

```
public static void foo(Class<? extends A> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    A a = clazz.newInstance(); // это будет экземпляр A, B Или C в зависимости от параметра clazz
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    foo(C.class);
    foo(B.class);
}
```

---

**Вариант 2** от @arg. Через фабрику.

Опишем контракт фабрики

```
interface Factory<T> {
   T create();
}
```

И добавим пару конкретных фабрик, которые и займутся созданием экземпляров.

```
class FactoryB implements Factory<B> {

    @Override
    public B create() {
        return new B();
    }
}

class FactoryC implements Factory<C> {

    @Override
    public C create() {
        return new C();
    }
}
```

В метод мы будем передавать уже не экземпляр `Class<?>` а фабрику:

```
public static void bar(Factory<? extends A> factory) {
    A a = factory.create(); это будет экземпляр A, B Или C в зависимости от переданной фабрики 
}

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Factory<? extends A> factory1 = new FactoryB();
    Factory<? extends A> factory2 = new FactoryC();
    bar(factory1);
    bar(factory2);
}
```

Comment: если в методе foo вызвать геттером поле name, то ведь геттер вернет null. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы геттер вернул - либо "В" либо "С" (в зависимости от передаваемого класса)?

Comment: @Stas0n, если вы в классы `A`, `B` и `C` добавите методы `String getName()`, возвращающие соответственно `null`, `"B"` и `"C"`, то, вызвав его в `foo()` (например `clazz.newInstance().getName()`) , получите именно то, что хотели.

Answer (score -1):

@Stas0n, не совсем понятно из вашего вопроса, вам нужен метод который создаёт экземпляр на основе существующего объекта (типа A, B или C), или на основе класса (Class)? Ниже привёл подход для первого случая. На мой взгляд он проще тем что не использует ни джинерики, ни рефлексию.

Еще одно решение - добавить в A метод который будет создавать новый экземпляр (так называемый фабричный метод):

```
class A {
    ...
    public A createInstance() {
        new A();
    }
}
class B extends A {
    ...
    // Переопределяем метод createInstance из A.
    // При этом тип возвращаемого значения может быть подтипом
    // возвращаемого значения родительского метода: A -> B
    public B createInstance() {
        new B();
    }
}
```

При такой реализации отдельный метод для создания экземпляров классов A, B и C нам не нужен.
Использование:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b1 = new B();
    // создаём сколько угодно новых экземпляров B
    B b2 = b1.createInstance(); 
    B b3 = b1.createInstance();
}
```